# CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback: callback not called

Tags: objective-c, screen

Why doesn't the function `displayChanged` get fired in the following code?

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

static void displayChanged(CGDirectDisplayID displayID, CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags, void *userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", displayID, flags); 
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(displayChanged, NULL);

        CFRunLoopRun();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm physically removing (and plugging in) my external display, but the function is never run.
Why?

Comment: What you're doing there is not really Objective C.  Try instantiating an Objective C object and put your "`CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback`" function call in that.  The reason I suggest this is because I think your code goes straight into "`CFRunLoopRun`" and any callback (not in an Objective C object context) never gets a chance to be called.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I don't think I understand, but could you provide some code doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the solution on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205442/register-for-windowserver-cgscreenrefreshcallback-cgscreenupdatemovecallback-in)

Before calling CFRunLoopRun you have to call NSApplicationLoad to establish a connection with the window server. This is the fixed code for the original question:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

static void displayChanged(CGDirectDisplayID displayID, CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags, void *userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"%u, %u", displayID, flags); 
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(displayChanged, NULL);

        NSApplicationLoad();  // establish a connection to the window server. In <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
        CFRunLoopRun();       // run the event loop
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution and also works on OS X 10.10 unlike my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback` to work, so I used distributed notifications instead:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"com.apple.BezelServices.BMDisplayHWReconfiguredEvent" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
            NSLog(@"Displays changed!");
        }];

        CFRunLoopRun();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the information on what name to use for the notification? "com.apple.BezelServices.BMDisplayHWReconfiguredEvent"
Is there documentation for this?

Comment: @MalachiHolden I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AppKit (and have a running `NSApplication` event loop), you can listen for the `NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification` notification.  Or, you can implement the `-applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:` method in your application delegate, which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: It is for a daemon, so I don't have any user interface.

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure, because you imported `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`, which includes AppKit.